# Asynchronus call in PHP Web page

Tags: php, asynchronous

I am new to PHP. I have a block of code on my webpage which I want to execute asynchronously. This block has following :
1. A `shell_exec` command.
2. A `ftp_get_content`.
3. Two image resize. 
4. One call to mysql for insert.

Is there way make this block async, So that the rest of the page loads quickly. 
Please ask if any more details required.

Comment: What will it do with the resultof `ftp_get_content`? If it's going to be included on the page, then nothing can be sent to the client until this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use curl to do a pseudo async call. You can put the async part of your code in a separate php file and call it via curl. For example:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'YOUR_URL_WITH_ASYNC_CODE');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I have used this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, dirname(__FILE__).'/getlargestimageasync.php?url='.$user_url);`, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the 4 tasks into a queue, maybe something like [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/), then have a background worker process this queue.